# bootstrap 3 grid system not working accordingly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to test bootstrap 3 grid system. Two columns in a row. In extra small devices like mobiles, it'll be stacked in one column and in small devices like in tablets, it'll be in 2 columns. But it's  not working accordingly in mobile devices. In mobile devices, it' showing in 2 columns whereas it should show in 1 column. Anything wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
   <html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <p>Item 1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <p>Item 2</p>
       </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close but you are using wrong column sizes.

If you want column to be 100% on tablets (small devices) and below you shouldn't use `col-sm-6` as it will still be on 2 columns on tablets, you should use `col-sm-12`, or `col-md-6` - `col-md-6` is saying that on desktop (medium) devices, 992px and above, that column width should be 50%, and below it should be 100%.

You also hide everything on mobiles (extra small 'xs' devices) with `hidden-xs`!

So try this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <p>Item 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <p>Item 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again we don't need to use `col-sm-12` as all sizes below smallest specified (in this case md-medium) are automatically 100%, this comes from mobile first design principle.

Comment: I'm using jQuery-One-Page-Nav (see https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) for tablet and desktop views, and it doesn't support for mobile view. So, I've to add another view without  using jQuery-One-Page-Nav for nav which will be supported in mobile view. So, I'll hide it by hidden-xs class, right? Sorry, if I sound silly. I'm new in responsive design world. You can see my webpage, which will give you better idea what am I talking about: http://107.180.106.101:8081/home.html . @Bojan

Comment: Yes, if you want to hide it on mobiles you can use `hidden-xs`. Let me know if my code works for tablets as desired.

Answer (score 0):

`hidden-xs` will hide the things in small screen. `col-sm-6` will automatically take `width:100%` for screen below `767px`; So `.col-xs-12` not required to include.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
              <p>Item 1</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
              <p>Item 2</p>
           </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `class="hidden-xs"` B'coz its hide the content when screen size is extra-small.